# How to set the default icon for all Java Swing windows?

Tags: java, swing, icons

How to set the default icon for all Java Swing windows?

Otherwise i have to set icons for every frame i created.

What's your suggestions?
Simple hackings are also accepted.

many thx

**Update: Best if the method you suggested can leave existing frame-creation codes untouched. thx**

Comment: Applications should have a single JFrame. Then you use JDialogs for other child windows of the application. So as krock suggestion you only need to change the icon in a single place when the JFrame is first created.

Answer (score 2):

Create an Abstact class that `extends JFrame`

In the constructor set your icon.

create child class that extends your new `Abstract Class` and call `super` in your constructor

```
public abstract class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    protected MainFrame() {
        this.setIconImage(null); // Put your own image instead of null
    }
}

public class ChildFrame extends MainFrame {
    public ChildFrame() {
        super();
    }
}
```

You can also just create object from your new class

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        this.setIconImage(null); // Put your own image instead of null
    }
}

public class Frame {

    private MainFrame mainframe = new MainFrame();

    public Frame() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also I believe all JDialogs inherit the icon from their parent window, so just need to worry about the JFrames/JWindows.

Comment: That's still an alternative method to set icon for every frame created. The biggest drawback is that it's not friendly with existing codes.

Comment: Also it doesn't work well with third party libraries spawning frames.

Answer (score 1):

To make windows icons changes globally without changing old code I am using this code snippet

```
public static void fixWindowsIcons(final List<Image> iconImages) {
    PropertyChangeListener l = new PropertyChangeListener() {

        private Window prevActiveWindow;

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            final Window o = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
                    .getActiveWindow();
            if (o != null && prevActiveWindow != o) {
                prevActiveWindow = o;
                List<Image> windowIcons = o.getIconImages();
                if (windowIcons == null || windowIcons.size() == 0) {
                    o.setIconImages(iconImages);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
            .addPropertyChangeListener("activeWindow", l); //$NON-NLS-1$
}
```